# Elastic search: map property types using wildcard for property name

Tags: php, elasticsearch, indexing, mapping, nosql

I want to apply a mapping to all properties. Can I do so without naming the property.

e.g.

```
'body' => [
    'doc_type' =>
        'properties' =>
            'networks' =>
                'properties' => [
                    '*' => ['type' => 'integer']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Instead of:

```
'properties' => [
    'vip10415' => ['type' => 'integer'],
    'vip86485' => ['type' => 'integer'],
    'vip23465' => ['type' => 'integer'],
    'vip97949' => ['type' => 'integer']
    ....
 ]
```

The reason I want to do this is because it isn't known until runtime what properties will be used.

I know queries can have wildcards, but haven't seen if mappings can. I looked at dynamic mappings but it didn't work like this.

Update:

I have tried inserting ints and letting elastic infer their type but it parses them as type 'long'. I am inserting using php and ensured they were ints with the intval() function.

Update:

'properties' are actually a sub field of a nested property 'Networks'. The name of the property to be stored as an int will not be known until runtime.

Update:

I've tried applying dynamic mapping templates recommend by @bittusarkar in the doc_type, but it throws an unable to parse mapping exception.

```
"dynamic_templates" => [
    "integers" => [
        "match_mapping_type" => "long",
        "mapping" => [
            "type" => "integer"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those fields are actually of integer types, you don't even need to define them explicitly in the mapping. Simply have an empty mapping and start indexing documents with these fields. Elasticsearch can infer the type of field and update the mapping dynamically. What you are asking can also be achieved through dynamic templates but IMO that would be an overkill.

Since you want the types to be `integer` instead of the default `long`, then [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) is the answer. See the mapping definition below. It will convert the type of any field whose type is detected to be of type `long` to type `integer`.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "mapping_name": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "convertToInteger": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "long",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that first (will update my question), using php I cast them with intval() but elastic parses them as long

Comment: You're right. It will automatically detect them as `long`. If you really want them to be of `int` type, then dynamic templates is the answer. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that requires 'mapping_name' to become the type name? Whereas I don't know what the name will be until runtime. I will update again.

Comment: From your updated question, I figure you don't know the name of the field. That is OK. You must know the name of the type though. `mapping_name` is the name of the type. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: Maybe I'm not adding it properly but it throws an unable to parse mapping exception.

Comment: Strange, works in sense put not php.. must be my problem somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

USe `Dynamic Templates`:

```
PUT /my_index
{
 "mappings": {
  "my_type": {
     "dynamic_templates": [
        {
           "analysed_string_template": {
              "match": "*",
              "mapping": {
                 "type": "integer"
              }
             }
          }
        ]
     }
    }
 }
```

Study more at [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)